# .Net core 3.1 app using Angular 10 works in Dev enviroment, but when I deployed in production enviroment shows net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular, iis, https, deployment, http-status-code-404

I development a .net core 3.1 with EFCore app using Angular 10.

**DEV MODE**

API works in PostMan
When I launch Back and Front end together by Visual Studio 2019 work too. Front calls API and it access database, it is ok. It usues IIS Express from VS

**PROD MODE**
However when I deployed in production enviroment , I use IIS 10 in Windows 10, firewall is turned off.

Whe I tried to use app by any browser, it shows net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Postman show error also.

**CODE**
*Backend code*

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
               {
                   if (env.IsDevelopment())
                   {
                      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                     // app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                  }
                   else
                   {
                        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                      app.UseHsts();
                   }
    
                  //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                   app.UseStaticFiles();
                   if (!env.IsDevelopment())
                  {
                      app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
                  }
    
                  app.UseRouting();
    
                  app.UseCors(option => { 
                           option.AllowAnyHeader();
                            option.AllowAnyMethod();
                            option.AllowAnyOrigin();
                           }
                   ); 
    
                   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                   {
                        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                            name: "default",
                            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                    });
    
            
    
                  app.UseSpa(spa =>
                  {
                      spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    
                       if (env.IsDevelopment())
                      {
                          // spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                          spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200/");
      
                       }
                   });
               }
          }
```

*Front End code*

**Package.json**

It was added ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js

**Proxy.conf.js**
In this file defaultwas set context: /api e target https://localhost:44306/, attribute secure: true and it saved as module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG

**IIS 10 on Windows 10**

It works Frontend part, it starts, it shows login, using mock options, it can enter main menu. When you need use api, so error happens.

Site Name: NSATest
path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NSATest
App Pool: NSATest

Bindings:

```
http, teste.nsa, 80

http, teste.nsa, 4200

https, teste.nsa, 443
```

Uses HTPS: Yes

**Summary**
Someone, could help me? This is the first time I am triyng to deply an app in Prod.

Comment: What URL gave you that error message? Make sure you understand IIS site bindings and use the right URL, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: There are many reasons for you get "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error. Have you tried opening Dev Tools (F12) and looking for errors in the console or network tab? I suggest you could check the IIS status about your website is running well.